# Session and included pages

Tags: php, session, include

My session don't seem to be saved. I have a log in page that saves the users id as a session. But when I leave the page and click on another page the sessions are not saved.

Here are my code. I have a main page called ***index***.php that look like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
       session_start();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> <HTML> <HEAD> </HEAD> <BODY>

<?php
$page_content = 'startpage.php';

if (isset($_GET['link']) && !empty($_GET['link']) ) {
    $page_content = $_GET['link'];
}

include "$page_content";
include 'menu.php'; 
include 'footer.php';  
?>
```

To login I use this page called ***admin.php***. Within this page I have loggin code that works fine. 
If the user has written right username and password then this happens:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;            
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The code above shows the current sessions variables. But as soon one click on another page the variables are left empty.

At the bottom of index.php are the ***footer.php*** page included, and it looks like this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){        
    echo "The sessions are not initiated. ";        
} 

if (empty ($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
    echo "The sessions are empty. ";
}

echo "<a href='index.php?link=admin.php'>Administration</a>";
?>
```

In this footer I have put two if questions to check the sessions. 
After I have succeded to logg in and clicked on an another page the if questions detect that my session are empty and not initiated.

How should I get the sessions to work?

Perhaps I should add that I use a rent database that use MySql.

Comment: where are your session_start()'s?

Comment: It is in my main page: index.php. Somehow it was not visible in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can use `$_SESSION` you should always start it with:

```
session_start()
```

Also, `session_start()` must always be called before you output anything on the page, otherwise it will not work properly

Comment: luke is right. Also remember to put the session_start(); before ANYTHING else on top of the page. No other code, no HTML, no whitespaces.

Comment: Yes I have session_start() at top of my index.php. 

If I would to put session_start() at top of my included page, like in admin.php, it would not come before my output text, since it is a included page. I tried once but it said it wasn't before output text.

Comment: Sorry my session_start() code in my question was not visible for some reason. I edited so you can see that I have written session_start() at the top.

Comment: is session_start() called in the login page too?

Comment: Ah no, it is also an included page.